# Having trouble replacing empty strings with NaN using Pandas.DataFranme.replace()

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which has some observations with empty strings which I want to replace with NaN (`np.nan`).

I am successfully replacing most of these empty strings using

```
df.replace(r'\s+',np.nan,regex=True).replace('',np.nan)
```

But I am still finding empty strings. For example, when I run

```
sub_df = df[df['OBJECT_COL'] == '']
sub_df.replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex = True)
print(sub_df['OBJECT_COL'] == '')
```

The output all returns `True`

Is there a different method I should be trying? Is there a way to read the encoding of these cells such that perhaps my `.replace()` is not effective because the encoding is weird?

Comment: what is you use `sub_df.replace(r'\s+',np.nan,regex=True).replace('',np.nan)`

Comment: that works! but returns a scalar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another Alternatives.

```
sub_df.replace(r'^\s+$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

OR, to replace an empty string and records with only spaces

```
sub.df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

Alternative:

using `apply()` with function lambda.

```
sub_df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()).replace('', np.nan)
```

### Just Example illustration:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
```

Example DataFrame having empty strings and whitespaces..

```
>>> sub_df
        col_A
0
1
2   somevalue
3  othervalue
4
```

### Solutions applied For the different conditions:

Best Solution:

1)

```
>>> sub_df.replace(r'\s+',np.nan,regex=True).replace('',np.nan)
        col_A
0         NaN
1         NaN
2   somevalue
3  othervalue
4         NaN
```

2) This works but partially not for both cases:

```
>>> sub_df.replace(r'^\s+$', np.nan, regex=True)
        col_A
0
1         NaN
2   somevalue
3  othervalue
4         NaN
```

3) This also works for both conditions.

```
>>> sub_df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)

            col_A
    0         NaN
    1         NaN
    2   somevalue
    3  othervalue
    4         NaN
```

4)  This also works for both conditions.

```
>>> sub_df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()).replace('', np.nan)
        col_A
0         NaN
1         NaN
2   somevalue
3  othervalue
4         NaN
```

Comment: thanks! the second replace worked as well as the commented out line, however both seem to return scalar when the columns are supposed to be objects (strings) - is there a way to return NaN as object type using .apply method?

Comment: 'sub_df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()).replace('', np.nan)'

^ this was the solution! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`pd.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) does **not** work in-place by default. You need to specify `inplace=True` explicitly:

```
sub_df.replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Or, alternatively, assign back to `sub_df`:

```
sub_df = sub_df.replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! however checking `sub_df['OBJECT_COL'] == ''` still returns all True values, so it does not appear to be working..

Answer (score 0):

Try [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['OBJECT_COL'] = np.where(df['OBJECT_COL'] == '', np.nan, df['OBJECT_COL'])
```

Comment: thanks! this does work, but I am getting the warning `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.`

Is there an effective way you recommend to call this on all columns of the DF?